# mysql query to insert some value concatinated with its id

Tags: mysql

how to insert some valu concatinated with its id i,e

```
UPDATE `hosting`.`invoice` SET `invoice_no` = 'wb/1420/'+'invoice_id 
                           WHERE `invoice`.`invoice_id` != 38;
```

Comment: Using google: https://www.google.com.au/#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ffb65513cbccee66&q=mysql+concatenate

Comment: Er, better idea: don't do this. Generally, you should not store data that can be easily calculated 'on-the-fly'.

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's [`concat`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) function

```
UPDATE `hosting`.`invoice` SET `invoice_no` = CONCAT('wb/1420/', invoice_id)
                           WHERE `invoice`.`invoice_id` != 38;
```

Comment: You are welcome, Do not forget to accept the answer by clicking on `correct` sign on the Left Hand Side of the Answer which helps you.Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```
$value = 'wb/1420/'.invoice_id;

UPDATE hosting.invoice SET invoice_no =$value  WHERE invoice.invoice_id != 38;
```